# Dimmer's closable setting not working

Tags: semantic-ui

Here is the [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/ccnuyan/gyoy230b/)

why the dimmer is still closable when initialized with `closable=false`?

```
$('.dimmer').dimmer({closable:false, on:'click'})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui segment dimmerable">
    <div class="ui dimmer">
      <div class="ui content">
        <div class="ui inverted center header">
          Dimmer
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    Segment
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please insert your code in the question to keep in trace on SO. See [ask]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to initialize a dimmer with settings is like the following : 
`$('selector').dimmer({settings}).dimmer('show')`

The way you're doing it modifies settings after initialization. so this is what you're code should look like :

[[DEMO]](https://jsfiddle.net/135nb9vy/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui segment dimmable">
    <div class="ui dimmer">
      <div class="ui content">
        <div class="ui inverted center header">
          Dimmer
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    Segment
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS** *(jQuery)*

```
$('.segment').click(function() {
  $('.dimmer')
    .dimmer({
     closable: false
    })
    .dimmer('show')
  ;
});
```